# Asymptotic behavior of the sequence $a_n=\sqrt{n+a_{n-1}}$

Tags: limits

Let $a_1=1$,  $a_n=\sqrt{n+a_{n-1}}$, $n\geq 1$. Show that $a_n=\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8\sqrt{n}}+o(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$.

How to prove, and is there any general method?

Comment: @Clayton I do not know. I see this problem in a personal contest. How to do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** First, prove $a_n<\sqrt{2n}$ for all $n$ (or anything similar in nature). Second, use the binomial theorem on $$\sqrt{n+a_{n-1}}=\sqrt{n}\cdot\left(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}\right)^{1/2}.$$ The first part guarantees that the binomial expansion works since $a_{n-1}/n<1$.

Can you handle the rest?

Comment: It is a little bit hard. I have seen $1/2$, $-1/8$ etc. But I could not go further.

Comment: @xldd: Indeed, the trick is to use this type of asymptotic twice: once for $a_n$ then again for $a_{n-1}$.